# Regex, match numbers and then a range of characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently attempting to write some relatively simple(?) regex which captures a group of numbers which are then followed by specific characters.

https://regexr.com/4jp9h is a good example, I actually thought it was working but the `4 garlic cloves` example chucked a spanner in the works. I've played with not matching whitespace / the spaces but haven't had much luck at all.

All of the other matches are fine, eg: 900g, 900kg, so on and so forth. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to stop the `4 garlic cloves` example from matching.

Anyone got any ideas? :)

Comment: You want to match `d900g`  or `900gd` also ? can you list out what will be desired result for such cases ?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57640147/372239) and add your test cases **with** expected result.

Answer (score 2):

```
\d+.?[g-k]
```

> Why `4 g` matches ?

You have `.?` which means match anything except new line once ( optional ), also i believe you want to match `kg` or `g`

So you can simply use

```
\d+k?g
```

- `\d+` - Match one or more digit
- `k?` - Match `k` ( optional )
- `g` - Match `g`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative version is...

```
\d+[Kk]?[Gg]\s
```

This is allows Kg, KG, g, G, but also then tries to ensure that there is nothing following directly after it, so in your test set...

```
there 900G          Match
900gvhello
hello garam masala
test g900gd
900kg               Match
4 garlic cloves
```

So it doesn't match `g900gd` or `4 garlic cloves`.

As pointed out, the `\s` on the end may be better with alternatives which match different things.

The fourth bird suggests *a non whitespace char `(?!\S)`*

Or an alternative may also be a non word character `[^w]`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I wasn't sure of the best way - it may be that or just not a word character ( I tried `[^\w]`).  Have to see what OP thinks.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly just not allow any space between the digit and the characters that follow:

```
\d+[^ ]?[g-k]
```

Notice, that `[g-k]` means that you accept a range of characters from g to k, i.e. examples like `900h`, `900ij` will match. If you do not want that and only want `k` and `g` characters to match, you can simply do:

```
\d+[^ ]?[gk]
```

If you are specifically interested in the `kg` order, you can simply do:

```
\d+[^ ]k?g --> this is same as Code Maniac answer \d+k?g
```

Obviously also notice the `ignore case flag i` - if you do not have that set, you will need to add upper-case letters to your regex as well.